Postfix won't start because it's "already running"
I'm trying to configure a VPS for my website and currently setting up email following a guide. I think I may have got into a bit of a mess through not really knowing what I'm doing yet. Most of the services I need seem to be working but postfix is causing trouble.
If I run sudo systemctl restart postfix then I get an error about the process already running but it's not. I can see afterwards that it is running. Almost like trying to start the service is spawning it twice or something.
root@mail:~# postfix status
postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is running: PID: 6296
root@mail:~# sudo kill -9 $(pgrep -f postfix)
root@mail:~# ps aux | grep postfix
root        6370  0.0  0.1   7076  2048 pts/0    S+   20:27   0:00 grep --color=auto postfix
root@mail:~# sudo systemctl restart postfix
Job for postfix.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status postfix.service" and "journalctl -xeu postfix.service" for details.
root@mail:~# systemctl status postfix.service
× postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-08-20 20:29:14 UTC; 6s ago
   Duration: 6min 17.125s
       Docs: man:postfix(1)
    Process: 6690 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 27ms

Aug 20 20:29:13 mail.mywebsite.com systemd[1]: Starting postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Aug 20 20:29:13 mail.mywebsite.com postfix[6696]: postfix/postlog: fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running
Aug 20 20:29:13 mail.mywebsite.com postfix/postfix-script[6696]: fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running
Aug 20 20:29:14 mail.mywebsite.com systemd[1]: postfix.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 20 20:29:14 mail.mywebsite.com systemd[1]: postfix.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 20 20:29:14 mail.mywebsite.com systemd[1]: Failed to start postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
root@mail:~# journalctl -xeu postfix.service
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit postfix.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 2769 and the job result is failed.
Aug 20 20:21:14 mail.mywebsite.com systemd[1]: Starting postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit postfix.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit postfix.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 3121.
Aug 20 20:21:14 mail.mywebsite.com postfix[6306]: postfix/postlog: fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running
Aug 20 20:21:14 mail.mywebsite.com postfix/postfix-script[6306]: fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running
Aug 20 20:21:15 mail.mywebsite.com systemd[1]: postfix.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit postfix.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Aug 20 20:21:15 mail.mywebsite.com systemd[1]: postfix.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit postfix.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 20 20:21:15 mail.mywebsite.com systemd[1]: Failed to start postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit postfix.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit postfix.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 3121 and the job result is failed.
Aug 20 20:29:13 mail.mywebsite.com systemd[1]: Starting postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit postfix.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit postfix.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 3474.
Aug 20 20:29:13 mail.mywebsite.com postfix[6696]: postfix/postlog: fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running
Aug 20 20:29:13 mail.mywebsite.com postfix/postfix-script[6696]: fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running
Aug 20 20:29:14 mail.mywebsite.com systemd[1]: postfix.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit postfix.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Aug 20 20:29:14 mail.mywebsite.com systemd[1]: postfix.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit postfix.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 20 20:29:14 mail.mywebsite.com systemd[1]: Failed to start postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit postfix.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit postfix.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 3474 and the job result is failed.
lines 362-430/430 (END)
root@mail:~# ps aux | grep postfix
root        6686  0.0  0.2  42848  4616 ?        Ss   20:29   0:00 /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/master -w
postfix     6687  0.0  0.4  43296  7680 ?        S    20:29   0:00 pickup -l -t unix -u -c
postfix     6689  0.0  0.4  43336  7808 ?        S    20:29   0:00 qmgr -l -t unix -u
root        6744  0.0  0.1   7076  2048 pts/0    S+   20:31   0:00 grep --color=auto postfix

More logs
root@mail:~# cat /var/log/syslog | grep postfix
2024-08-21T18:54:42.674376+00:00 mail postfix/postfix-script[24482]: the Postfix mail system is not running
2024-08-21T18:54:50.194645+00:00 mail systemd[1]: Starting postfix@-.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)...
2024-08-21T18:54:50.728346+00:00 mail postmulti[24793]: postfix/postlog: starting the Postfix mail system
2024-08-21T18:54:50.728474+00:00 mail postfix/postfix-script[24793]: starting the Postfix mail system
2024-08-21T18:54:50.735553+00:00 mail postfix/master[24795]: daemon started -- version 3.8.6, configuration /etc/postfix
2024-08-21T18:54:50.738846+00:00 mail systemd[1]: Started postfix@-.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -).
2024-08-21T18:54:50.745769+00:00 mail systemd[1]: Starting postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
2024-08-21T18:54:50.769912+00:00 mail postfix[24806]: postfix/postlog: fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running
2024-08-21T18:54:50.770062+00:00 mail postfix/postfix-script[24806]: fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running
2024-08-21T18:54:51.771958+00:00 mail systemd[1]: postfix.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2024-08-21T18:54:51.772098+00:00 mail systemd[1]: postfix.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2024-08-21T18:54:51.772427+00:00 mail systemd[1]: Failed to start postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent.


root@mail:~# cat /var/log/mail.log
2024-08-21T08:15:35.930594+00:00 mail dovecot: master: Warning: Time moved forwards by 0.100082 seconds - adjusting timeouts.
2024-08-21T18:53:52.905868+00:00 mail postfix/postfix-script[24461]: stopping the Postfix mail system
2024-08-21T18:53:52.907381+00:00 mail postfix/master[6686]: terminating on signal 15
2024-08-21T18:54:42.674376+00:00 mail postfix/postfix-script[24482]: the Postfix mail system is not running
2024-08-21T18:54:50.728474+00:00 mail postfix/postfix-script[24793]: starting the Postfix mail system
2024-08-21T18:54:50.735553+00:00 mail postfix/master[24795]: daemon started -- version 3.8.6, configuration /etc/postfix
2024-08-21T18:54:50.770062+00:00 mail postfix/postfix-script[24806]: fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running

My service file looks like this
root@mail:~# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service
[Unit]
Description=Postfix Mail Transport Agent
Documentation=man:postfix(1)
Conflicts=sendmail.service exim4.service
ConditionPathExists=/etc/postfix/main.cf

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/postfix reload
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/postfix stop
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Any ideas where to start looking to resolve this? Thanks

Well, where's Postfix's own logs?

@NikitaKipriyanov I've added logs from /var/log/syslog and /var/log/mail.log if thats what you mean

Don't use kill -9. It kills the process without giving it a chance to properly shutdown. In the case of the postfix, it leaves /var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid file in place and the presence of this file causes the postfix to detect that it is still running.

Good to know. For what it's worth, I've stopped the process with sudo systemctl stop postfix, removed master.pid and tried restarting and I get the same errors

master.pid is supposed to be removed automatically on systemctl stop postifx. If it was still present after the stop then there is something wrong with your system.

it was not removed when I called stop so the question would be where do I start trying to debug that problem

The systemd unit file doesn't look like the one provided by Ubuntu. Re-install the postfix package from the system packages.
